# Customizable starter design for jQuery Mobile-DW-Add more pages?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Practicing offline with the template provided by Adobe for their starter JQuery Mobile site example.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/dw-template-jqmobile.html

But I find I can't seem to build more than 4 pages.  I made the fifth page with content and I got a black screen.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have ab error in your HTML.

Here's an example from adobe built with extra fifth page. Copy it in the single file and test it, all js/css files are hardcoded so you don't need to worry:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>`enter code here`
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://www.maja-klajic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page">
            <!-- The 'logo' DIV below was added to the default markup -->
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div data-role="header" class="heading">
                <h1>Your Organization</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <ul data-role="listview" class="mainmenu">
                    <li><a href="#page2">Who We Are</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page3">What We Do</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page4">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page5">Fift Page</a></li>                 
                </ul>       
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>&copy;2011 &bull; Your Organization Name</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="page2">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Who We Are</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <p>Nunc auctor bibendum eros. Maecenas porta accumsan mauris. Etiam enim enim, elementum sed, bibendum quis, rhoncus non, metus. Fusce neque dolor, adipiscing sed, consectetuer et, lacinia sit amet, quam. Suspendisse wisi quam, consectetuer in, blandit sed, suscipit eu, eros. Etiam ligula enim, tempor ut, blandit nec, mollis eu, lectus. Nam cursus. Vivamus iaculis. Aenean risus purus, pharetra in, blandit quis, gravida a, turpis. Donec nisl. Aenean eget mi. Fusce mattis est id diam. Phasellus faucibus interdum sapien. Duis quis nunc. Sed enim.</p>       
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>&copy;2011 &bull; Your Organization Name</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="page3">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>What We Do</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <h2>Maecenas porta accumsan mauris</h2>
                <p>Nunc auctor bibendum eros. Maecenas porta accumsan mauris. Etiam enim enim, elementum sed, bibendum quis, rhoncus non, metus. Fusce neque dolor, adipiscing sed, consectetuer et, lacinia sit amet, quam. Suspendisse wisi quam</p>
                <figure>
                    <img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="photo" width="120" />
                    <figcaption>Duis a eros lit ora tor quent per conu bia nos tra per.</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <p>Consectetuer in, blandit sed, suscipit eu, eros. Etiam ligula enim, tempor ut, blandit nec, mollis eu, lectus. Nam cursus. Vivamus iaculis. Aenean risus purus, pharetra in, blandit quis, gravida a, turpis. Donec nisl. Aenean eget mi. Fusce mattis est id diam. Phasellus faucibus interdum sapien. Duis quis nunc. Sed enim.</p>
                <p>Nunc auctor bibendum eros. Maecenas porta accumsan mauris. Etiam enim enim, elementum sed, bibendum quis, rhoncus non, metus. Fusce neque dolor, adipiscing sed, consectetuer et, lacinia sit amet, quam. Suspendisse wisi quam, consectetuer in, blandit sed, suscipit eu, eros. Etiam ligula enim, tempor ut, blandit nec, mollis eu, lectus. Nam cursus. Vivamus iaculis. Aenean risus purus, pharetra in, blandit quis, gravida a, turpis. Donec nisl. Aenean eget mi. Fusce mattis est id diam. Phasellus faucibus interdum sapien. Duis quis nunc. Sed enim.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>&copy;2011 &bull; Your Organization Name</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="page4">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>About Us</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <p>Nunc auctor bibendum eros. Maecenas porta accumsan mauris. Etiam enim enim, elementum sed, bibendum quis, rhoncus non, metus. Fusce neque dolor, adipiscing sed, consectetuer et, lacinia sit amet, quam. Suspendisse wisi quam, consectetuer in, blandit sed, suscipit eu, eros. Etiam ligula enim, tempor ut, blandit nec, mollis eu, lectus. Nam cursus. Vivamus iaculis. Aenean risus purus, pharetra in, blandit quis, gravida a, turpis. Donec nisl. Aenean eget mi. Fusce mattis est id diam. Phasellus faucibus interdum sapien. Duis quis nunc. Sed enim.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>&copy;2011 &bull; Your Organization Name</h4>
            </div>
        </div>          

        <div data-role="page" id="page5">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>This is fifth page</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <p>This is fifth page</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>&copy;2011 &bull; Your Organization Name</h4>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </body>
</html>
```